# how to avoid Javascript weird Float behavior?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, tofixed

Why is it that trying to add 2.05 with 1.01 
returns this value?

```js
console.log(2.05+1.01); // -> 3.0599999999999996?
```

is using toFixed() the only way around it?

```js
console.log((2.05+1.01).toFixed(2))
```

How can I avoid this behavior, so it won't get me by surprise in the inner calculations of my code.

Comment: what do you mean by 'weird' behavior? you can always format your float values the way you want it to display.

Comment: why is this behavior weird? It's how floating point numbers to a certain precision always act

Comment: If this is currency the easiest solution is to work in the smaller unit; `205 + 101 === 306`

Answer (score 1):

This is because javascript's floating point precision only goes up to 14 places. The only real ways around it are multiplying each number by a high number or doing what you said.